# Mocking aggregate classes

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

we have the following method inside class C:

```
public static void m(a A, b B)
{
......

A1 a1=new a.getA1;  //Not sure about the syntax
Double d1= a.getInfo;
.....

if (d1>5.0)
  {
   b.add(d1,a1)   
  }
}
```

A is another class. Inside A, we have a variable declared as type of class A1 (this makes A an aggregated class I think). I have defined the following as mock objects:

```
private mockA = mock(A.class);
private mockA1 = mock(A1.class);   // Please help with syntax
private mockB = mock(B.class)
```

Also

```
when(mockA.getInfo()).thenReturn(6.4);
when(mockA.getA1()).thenReturn(mockA1);    //Please help with syntax
when(mockA1.m2()).thenReturn("Some More Details");   // Please help with syntax  

m(mockA, mockB);

// In case > 5.0
verify(mockB,times(1)).add(6.4,mockB);

//in case < 5.0
verify(mockB,times(0)).add(anyDouble,any(B.class));
```

Could you please help if the syntax for mocking A1 object, and using it in when/verify is correct?

Another question is if it is not necessary to create mock for a1, which syntax should be used? For example, is the following ok?

```
 when(mockA.getA1().m2())).thenReturn("Something");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for mocking A1 is no different than for mocking A. You just need to make sure that any interactions with A1 (e.g. `mockA1.m2()`) are either mocked or contain valid data (if A1 isn't a mock).

If you're mocking A1, then your code is correct:

```java
A mockA = mock(A.class);
A1 mockA1 = mock(A1.class);

when(mockA.getInfo()).thenReturn(6.4);
when(mockA.getA1()).thenReturn(mockA1);
when(mockA1.m2()).thenReturn("Some More Details");
```

If A1 is not a mock, then you don't need to mock its methods like is done with `when(mockA1.m2()).thenReturn(...)` above:

```java
A mockA = mock(A.class);
A1 realA1 = new A1();

when(mockA.getInfo()).thenReturn(6.4);
when(mockA.getA1()).thenReturn(realA1);
```